# Can the reflection of a candle appear brighter than the candle itself?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics

We set a candle down on a table, and next to it, a reflecting curved surface.

The light from the candle flame is of course, dispersing, spreading out and hence the apparent brightness is dropping as the distance (from our eye to the flame) squared.

The image in the mirror however is presumably made up of the parallel light rays, those reflected at the exact angle to reach our eye. It seems the apparent brightness of the reflected image should be independent of distance. (It will, of course, depend on the distance from the candle to the surface, but let's assume that's small)

Here is a rough diagram mapping this out:
[image]

Thus as we move away, is there not some point beyond which the reflection appears brighter?

Going further, could we not go an infinite distance away and the reflection still appear bright?

I'm very interested to hear the practical limitations here (such as the attainable quality of a reflective surface) but also whether the pure thought experiment holds up.

Comment: No the thought experiment is set up wrong. When you postulate "The image in the mirror however is presumably made up of the parallel light rays", this is entirely wrong. The rays towards the mirror disperse just as much as the direct ray. In fact, assuming you had a perfect mirror and could not see the extents of it, there is no way you would ever tell if you are looking directly at a candle or a reflection of it.

Comment: This is a great point, I've updated the question slightly and changed the image to better reflect my real query. For a curved reflecting surface, it seems now to be possible for the reflected light rays to be parallel, yes?

Comment: No, you cannot do that either. This is because of Conservation Of Étendue. Relevant xkcd what-if: [Fire From Moonlight](https://what-if.xkcd.com/145/). In brief: you **cannot** parallelize the rays, even with a curved mirror.

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae, if that is the case, then it is possible to parallelize any of the rays from two separate sources? I assume not.

Comment: @Zephyr Ok, I just realized I am **dead wrong**. Yes you can make it so that the reflection is brighter, at least **in a particular direction**. This is what **parabolic reflectors** do. This assumes that 1) the light source is a point 2) you do not care that the image arrives distorted (but a point is a point, not a full image 3) it only works in a particular direction. In all other directions the reflection is much dimmer.

Comment: I'm not sure dead wrong is fair, I'm thinking through etendue now (news to me but very interesting) and working out if it's relevant. But just returning to simple geometric optics, surely, for any particular point on the near-side of the "surface" of the flame there must be a point on the reflective surface where it is reflected towards the observer. And if the observer is sufficiently far away are these reflected light rays not effectively parallel?

Comment: @Zephyr The point where you go wrong is that you are only considering **one ray from each point on the candle**. That is not how it works. Every point on the candle (the flame of the candle to be precise) is an omnidirectional light source, that transmits rays in all directions. But like I said: if you make the candle small enough to be considered a point source of light, then this issue becomes moot. The only other way the reflection can appear brighter is if the reflector is closer to the observer than the candle is. Only then can you beat the Conservation of Étendue.

Comment: But if every point on the flame is an omnidirectional source, then at every point there must be some fraction of the emitted light which satisfies the geometric conditions and will be reflected directly to the observer, correct? It's not that I'm only considering a single ray from each point, it's that only one ray (the one which is perfectly orientated) from each point on the surface is of interest.

Comment: Well the intensity is **not** made up of a couple of singular rays, but bundles of rays. What you are trying to achieve is to make more rays reach you through the reflector than the direct path,. But in any case, I have already answered: **yes you can get it such that for a small enough source of light, you can make the reflection much more intense, but only in one particular direction** (or a *lobe* to be precise). This is the direct purpose of parabolic reflectors, and the most obvious example you can get of this phenomena is a spotlight or a car headlight.

Comment: It is important to define what you mean by "brightness".  To me, the most intuitive definition is one which doesn't change if you change the size of the source leaving everything else constant--from two candles side-by-side, you get twice the light, but the "brightness" stays the same.  However, another possible definition, and it seems the one you're using, is proportional to the total amount of light from the source that makes its way to your retina.  So you would say that two candles have a "brightness" that is twice one candle.  Is this correct?

Comment: In your sketch, the angles of reflection are not consistent. The reflected beam spreads as well. Use the tangent to see this

Answer (score 1):

**Edit applied** - the question has change from a flat mirror to a curved mirror. Original answer below.

With a concave mirror surface it would in principle be possible to generate some parallel rays of light from the candle that would be brighter than the candle for a longer distance, however, there are some practical difficulties.

The size of the candle is finite so the light comes from a volume rather than a fixed point, which makes generating really parrallel rays from all parts of the candle impossible. In reality what would happen is that over distance the focussed light intensity would slowly drop.

**Original answer for flat mirror** - or at least the original image had a flat mirror

If the candle flame is symmetrical then the path to the eye which includes mirror reflection will always be longer and so the light will always be more dispersed in the case of the mirror as it has passed over a longer distance....

There are a couple of other things to consider...

- The fraction of light reflected by the mirror will not be 100%, though it may be close to 100%
- If the mirror is in any way curved and non-parallel then the light from the candle might be brighter for a certain range of distances if the mirror focuses light from the candle somewhere in the direction of the eye and close to the eye.

[In London a building, nicknamed the 'walkie talkie' has curved windows which one day focussed sunlight enough to damage](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-27425560) a couple of cars and started a carpet to smoulder (burn with low intensity) in a shop. The building was not a perfect reflector by any means or the correct geometry to really focus the suns rays, just somewhat curved and curved enough to focus the sunlight enough to do the damage

Answer (score -1):

light is in a form of light energy,so there will not be make up of light from nothing.The experiment is only collecting the light from other direction to one,not making it brighter.Infact,the four light Ray will only convert to a significant point,and at that pt you won't say the candle is brighter.Its only an image of the candle.

Comment: Tough the OP probably mean brighter than the direct image.